# How can I ran nmap script on a Mac OS X?

Tags: nmap, macos

I've installed nmap in my Mac OS X tried.

I'm not on Linux, I couldn't find the script directory. I ran

`sudo nmap -sV --script vulners 69.164.220.111`

Password:

I kept getting

```
Starting Nmap 6.49BETA4 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-01-07 14:35 EST
NSE: failed to initialize the script engine:
/usr/local/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:801: 'vulners' did not match a category, filename, or directory
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        /usr/local/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:801: in function 'get_chosen_scripts'
        /usr/local/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:1249: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?

QUITTING!
```

Do you know what I did wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

according to `nmap --help` on my MacBook Air:

```
 --script=<Lua scripts>: <Lua scripts> is a comma separated list of
           directories, script-files or script-categories
```

so it looks like you need `--script=vulners`

Comment: Let me try thanks